# Как очистить корзину woocommerce перед добавлением товара?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть интернет-магазин на `woocommerce`.

На странице товара **CONTINUE** идет переход в корзину,

```
<form name="DOPBSPCalendar-form1" id="DOPBSPCalendar-form1" action="" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="DOPBSPCalendar-add-to-cart1" id="DOPBSPCalendar-add-to-cart1" value="CONTINUE">
</form>
```

где доступ к товару получаю через `$_POST['DOPBSPCalendar-add-to-cart1']`.

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в момент перехода корзина была полностью пустой и добавился только 1 текущий товар 
(т.е. удалялись все предыдущие действия пользователя, если ранее он уже добавлял добавлял какой-либо товар и в корзине эта информация хранится)

Очистить саму корзину я могу с помощью такой записи:

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
```

Пройтись по элементам корзины вот так

```
global $wpdb;
global $DOPBSP;
global $DOPBSPWooCommerce;
$getcart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
foreach ( $getcart as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $reservations = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$DOPBSPWooCommerce->tables->woocommerce.' WHERE cart_item_key="%s" AND token="%s" AND product_id=%d', $cart_item["key"], $cart_item["dopbsp_token"], $cart_item["product_id"]));
    $js = json_decode($reservations[0]->data);
}
```

Но, как совместить эти действия так, чтобы сам добавляемый товар при этом не очищался?

Comment: Сделайте по клику аякс запрос, в обработчике сначала очистите корзину, после добавьте нужный товар и если все успешно в success редиректим куда нам нужно

Comment: @Taarim вот у меня и сложность с тем, чтобы очистить корзину и добавить нужный товар

Comment: в приведенной верстке мало инфы - дополните кодом вывода товара где есть идентификатор - он обычно в форму подставляется.

У вас по идее как в стоке по сабмиту идет добавление а нужно при аякс запросе отдельно отправить идентификатор, чтобы можно было смело очищать корзину и после по идентификатору добавить текущий

Comment: @Taarim дополнил

Comment: Ого жесть какая получилась о_О Так точно делать не стоит) Я имел ввиду на фронте вы ведь выводите товар? Там доступен его идентифкатор вы его разве не используете? Приведите более расширенный код карточки товара. Потому что сложно гадать как сделать правильно не видя структуру фронта

Comment: Сейчас поясню - там смысл примерно такой, как в демо https://pinpoint.world/demos/wordpress-booking/product/booking-calendar/
только 2ой шаг объединен с 3им (т.е. корзина совмещена с чекаутом) и шаг 2 где показаны товары в корзине мне нужен, т.к. товар всегда один, а цена берется не из товара, а из букинга, поэтому и карточка товара мне не нужна, нужно только, чтобы сам товар попадал в корзину.